# Maximum update depth exceeded. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an array of objects that I am getting from redux, and within those objects are arrays of data. I am attempting to modify the array and store the data in redux again. I've tried may things such as useCallback() and useEffect(), but no matter what I try I get an error that says : Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. 
or
“Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.”
I realize that the reason this is happening is because I'm calling the data from redux, modifying it with data that I am getting from a urql subscription and then re-sending it to redux. I am just at a loss as to how I can work around this problem. If anyone has encountered this problem and found a solution I'd be very happy to get an answer on this.
link to the project.
https://github.com/DarekR88/eog-react-visualization

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend } from 'recharts';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Card from '../components/Card';
// import { actions } from '../Features/DataCon/reducer'
import { actions } from '../Features/MultipleMetrics/sliceReducer';

export default function MultiChart() {
  const multiData = useSelector(state => state.multipleData.multipleData);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const injValveData = useSelector(state => state.injValve.injValveData);
  const oilTempData = useSelector(state => state.oilTemp.oilTempData);
  const flareTempData = useSelector(state => state.flareTemp.flareTempData);
  const waterTempData = useSelector(state => state.waterTemp.waterTempData);
  const casingPressureData = useSelector(state => state.casingPressure.casingPressureData);
  const tubingPressureData = useSelector(state => state.tubingPressure.tubingPressureData);
  // const displayData = useSelector(state => state.chartData.chartData);

///////////////////// this is the block of code that is causing the error to be thrown //////////////

let chartData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(multiData)); // getting the redux data set 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartData.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
        if (chartData[i].metric === 'injValveOpen') {
          chartData[i].measurements.shift();
          chartData[i].measurements.push(injValveData);
          dispatch(actions.multipleData(chartData));
// where the data is modified and the dispatch is sent out
        } else if (chartData[i].metric === 'flareTemp') {
          chartData[i].measurements.shift();
          chartData[i].measurements.push(flareTempData);
          dispatch(actions.multipleData(chartData));
        } else if (chartData[i].metric === 'waterTemp') {
          chartData[i].measurements.shift();
          chartData[i].measurements.push(waterTempData);
          dispatch(actions.multipleData(chartData));
        } else if (chartData[i].metric === 'oilTemp') {
          chartData[i].measurements.shift();
          chartData[i].measurements.push(oilTempData);
          dispatch(actions.multipleData(chartData));
        } else if (chartData[i].metric === 'casingPressure') {
          chartData[i].measurements.shift();
          chartData[i].measurements.push(casingPressureData);
          dispatch(actions.multipleData(chartData));
        } else if (chartData[i].metric === 'tubingPressure') {
          chartData[i].measurements.shift();
          chartData[i].measurements.push(tubingPressureData);
          dispatch(actions.multipleData(chartData));
        }
      }
    }
  }, [multiData]);

/////////// this is the block of code that is causing the error to be thrown ////////////


  const names = {
    injValveOpen: 'INJ Valve Open',
    oilTemp: 'Oil Temp',
    tubingPressure: 'Tubing Pressure',
    flareTemp: 'Flare Temp',
    casingPressure: 'Casing Pressure',
    waterTemp: 'Water Temp',
    default: 'metric',
  };

  const colors = {
    injValveOpen: '#1BD82A',
    oilTemp: '#000000',
    tubingPressure: '#FF0000',
    flareTemp: '#FFB201',
    casingPressure: '#830BEE',
    waterTemp: '#000CFF',
    default: '#00FFE0',
  };

  return (
    <>
      {multiData.map(i => {
        if (i.metric === injValveData.metric) {
          return <Card metric={names[i.metric]} data={`${injValveData.value}${injValveData.unit}`} />;
        } else if (i.metric === oilTempData.metric) {
          return <Card metric={names[i.metric]} data={`${oilTempData.value} ${oilTempData.unit}`} />;
        } else if (i.metric === flareTempData.metric) {
          return <Card metric={names[i.metric]} data={`${flareTempData.value} ${flareTempData.unit}`} />;
        } else if (i.metric === waterTempData.metric) {
          return <Card metric={names[i.metric]} data={`${waterTempData.value} ${waterTempData.unit}`} />;
        } else if (i.metric === casingPressureData.metric) {
          return <Card metric={names[i.metric]} data={`${casingPressureData.value} ${casingPressureData.unit}`} />;
        } else if (i.metric === tubingPressureData.metric) {
          return <Card metric={names[i.metric]} data={`${tubingPressureData.value} ${tubingPressureData.unit}`} />;
        }
      })}
      <LineChart width={1000} height={600}>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="at" type="category" allowDuplicatedCategory={false} />
        <YAxis dataKey="value" />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend layout="vertical" verticalAlign="middle" align="right" />
        {multiData.map(i => {
          return (
            <Line
              dataKey="value"
              data={i.measurements}
              name={names[i.metric]}
              key={i.metric}
              dot={false}
              stroke={colors[i.metric]}
            />
          );
        })}
      </LineChart>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: why is the chartdata in useEffect?

Comment: Keep in mind that useEffect will be called on every single render whenever one of it's dependencies change. From the looks of your code, you are modifying multiData within your useEffect, and multiData is also a dependency of your effect, thus causing an infinite loop of rendering.